# Kind of string.format while binding in Silverlight and TextBlocks?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, binding

I have XAML like this.. Basically it concatenates multiple strings that bind to different properties. Let's say for some reason I do not want to expose another property on VM to have it as single property.

Is there any other XAML-bind way to make it more compact?

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Added by " FontSize="10" Foreground="#2C2C2C" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Document.MEMUser.UserName}" Foreground="#2C2C2C" FontSize="10" />
    <TextBlock Text=" on " FontSize="10" Foreground="#2C2C2C"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CreatedOn, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToStringConverter}}" Foreground="#2C2C2C" FontSize="10" />
    <!--BIND COMMANDS TO PARENT ViewModel to process operations-->
    <Button Content="Delete" Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
    <Button Content="Download" Command="{Binding DataContext.DownloadCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<Run>` elements within the `TextBlock`:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock FontSize="10" Foreground="#2C2C2C">
       <Run Text="Added by "  />
       <Run Text="{Binding Document.MEMUser.UserName}" />
       <Run Text=" on " />
       <Run Text="{Binding CreatedOn, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToStringConverter}}" />
    </TextBlock>
    <!--BIND COMMANDS TO PARENT ViewModel to process operations-->
    <Button Content="Delete" Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
    <Button Content="Download" Command="{Binding DataContext.DownloadCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: @katit: indeed it should, thanks for spotting it.  I've now edited my answer to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a converter to concatenate all the strings, you need to pass some object instance that embraces all the properties needed.

Side note: you can set fontsize and foreground in the StackPanel as TextBlock.FontSize and TextBlock.Foreground